# Describing union of input types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say we have a wrapper object:

```
interface Wrapper<T> {
  value: T
}
```

I want to design a function that receives `Wrapper` objects as arguments (with possibly different T) and returns one of them:

```
function <T extends ReadonlyArray<Wrapper<any>>>(...args: T) { ... }
```

The return type of such function should be Wrapper<(union of input Ts)>. How do I describe such return type in Typescript, without losing the input types (that is, not `Wrapper<any>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The function will capture the correct types, the any in the constraint is used as a wild card, the any will not make it into `T` (depending on variance you could replace it with `unknown` or `never` but it's usually not worth it)

If `T` contains an array of wrappers, you can get a union of the types passed to wrppper using an type index query:

```
function getOne<T extends ReadonlyArray<Wrapper<any>>>(...args: T): Wrapper<T[number]['value']> {
    return args[0];
}

let x = getOne({
    value: { a: 1}
}, {
    value: { b: 1}
})

// let x: Wrapper<{
//     a: number;
// } | {
//     b: number;
// }>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB09APAFQD5kBvAKGWQDc4AbAVwgC5l8yBfMsmekBMYAHsQyAOYQwAeRAQCyCAA9IIACYBnZACUIcFcNoBPAIJQMB3Oiw4ouOCAOFHACgB0buFFFqW+AJQtLbDx8AG0QegBbACNoAF0QgHIaBggE2OJySkooCXooEQ8vEIAGWIBuDi5aCWQFZABeMQlpCCdMrOTGFhJkOBYARk52ABpSCg66LtJkKIGh3y4AekXkarBagIwgm3JlrMo+5HDo6Aq99mQAHzG9-dmjyJioM5X2QiA)